# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContext.release(PrimeFacesContext.java:26)

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-extensions

I have upgraded my application from faces 2.1 to 2.2.The following error showing up when I am accessing my application in browser.Using javax.faces-2.2.4 jar, primefaces-4.0 jar 
and primefaces-extensions-1.2.0 jar in my application

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContext.release(PrimeFacesContext.java:26)
        at org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContext.release(PrimeFacesContext.java:28)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:665)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
```

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

This is my faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
```

Comment: WebLogic Server is 10.3.6.0

Comment: It seems you should leave one PF's jar in the classpath of your webapp, try to remove the extension's one to see.

Comment: I have removed primefaces-extensions-1.2.0 jar from application WEB-INF/lib then also getting the same error java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContext.release(PrimeFacesContext.java:26)
 at org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContext.release(PrimeFacesContext.java:28)
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:612)
 at

Comment: Make sure that's removed also through the EDI. Make a clean & build.

Comment: How exactly did you upgrade to JSF 2.2? WebLogic 10.x doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

My problem got solved by not exporting (`Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export->Uncheck primefaces and extension jar checkbox`)

`primefaces-4.0 jar` and `primefaces-extensions-1.2.0 jar`.

These two jars are present in application's WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: This means that the jars were duplicated in the project lib somehow ?

Answer (score -2):

This error appeared when informed hibernate.cfg.xml in the address of the packet in the class map. 
Make notes of all the configuration files if you are not wrong addresses.